# footer absolute to bottom but within wrap

Tags: html, css

I want my footer to be bottom:0 but in the same time it's within the wrap, which width equal to 968px. I tried playing with absolute and relative, not work..

Comment: Provide code please. What have you done?

Comment: @dwhite.me sorry forgot to include the code.. updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your wrapper is only 588px in height. So the footer is going to the bottom of that.

You can fix this, by:

```
.wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    min-height: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -484px;
}
```